# How to add 'clearpath_base/AckermannSetpt' msg in ROS Kinetic?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, add-message-files, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to add 'clearpath_base/AckermannSetpt' msg in ROS Kinetic?

http://wiki.ros.org/clearpath_base

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307093/how-to-add-%27clearpath_base/ackermannsetpt%27-msg-in-ros-kinetic?/) by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-10-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-30**:
Are you trying to upgrade a clearpath vehicle to ROS Kinetic? Or do you just want to use the messages in `clearpath_base` for your own purposes?

**Comment by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on 2018-10-30**:
Hi
I want to use the messages in clearpath_base for my own purposes?
Specifically 'clearpath_base/AckermannSetpt'. Because it contains timestamp, steering, throttle and braking. Exactly what I need.
Thank you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-30**:
I would suggest to take a look at [ackermann_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/ackermann_msgs).

Perhaps that can be used.

It's already a stand-alone msg package and easily installed as it's released into Indigo, Kinetic and Melodic.

**Comment by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on 2018-10-30**:
Problems with ackermann_msgs are its variable names can be misleading to someone and its data types are 'float', I prefer 'double'.
Is there no way to install [clearpath msg](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/clearpath_base/html/namespaceclearpath__base_1_1msg_1_1__AckermannSetpt.html) ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-30**:
How to do what?

**Comment by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on 2018-10-30**:
Problems with ackermann_msgs are its variable names can be misleading to someone and its data types are 'float', I prefer 'double'. Is there no way to install [clearpath msg](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/clearpath_base/html/namespaceclearpath__base_1_1msg_1_1__AckermannSetpt.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest using `ackermann_msgs` as:

1. it's a message that is used by many other nodes and controllers
2. `clearpath_msgs` is old, unused and unmaintained

If you must use `clearpath_msgs`, you can find it [here](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/clearpath_base).

You'll have to `git clone ..` it to your Catkin workspace, make sure to have all dependencies installed (see #q252478 for the general procedure) and then build the workspace.

> Problems with ackermann_msgs are its variable names can be misleading to someone

This I don't understand.

> and its data types are 'float', I prefer 'double'.

It's up to you, but for values this small I would be surprised it really makes a difference.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on 2018-10-31**:
Thanks..it worked :)